# drupal 6 how to automatically add content type to parent in menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is there a way to make every content type default to the parent in the menu.

ie say i have content type called "cats" . How do i make all "cats"  automatically sit inside "pet" menu item. Also can i alphabetically sort "cats" in the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this programatically, with a custom module.

in [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_nodeapi) op=="insert", you can check for the $node->type and then use [menu_link_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/menu_link_save/6) to create the menu item.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you cannot manipulate the order of menu items -- however you could perhaps accomplish the same effect by using Views.

You can default every content type to a specific menu on admin/build/menu/settings and change the "Default menu for content" setting to your menu. But this will default ALL content types to that menu. For this problem you might also want to look into views.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://jan.tomka.name/blog/programmatically-creating-menu-items-drupal) does exactly what you want (and it's very easy to do)

This also uses `menu_link_save()`, but you won't have to create a module.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a [Drupal module](http://drupal.org/project/automenu) that does this

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like it can be accomplished by setting up the menus appropriately. Take a look at the video [here](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-menu-system-demystified) where the trainer sets up pretty much exactly what I think you've described.

Hope that helps...